# go list: no matching versions for query "latest"

Tags: go, dependencies, go-modules, package-management

I am trying to run the `go list -mod=readonly -m -u -json all` command on the [opentelemetry-collector-contrib](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib) project.

It fails with the below error:

```
$ go list -mod=readonly -m -u -json all
go list -m: loading module retractions for github.com/DataDog/datadog-agent/pkg/trace/exportable@v0.0.0-20201016145401-4646cf596b02: no matching versions for query "latest"
go list -m: loading module retractions for github.com/influxdata/line-protocol/v2@v2.0.0-20210428091617-0567a5134992: no matching versions for query "latest"
$ echo $?
1
```

I am using go 1.16.5:

```
$ go version
go version go1.16.5 linux/amd64
```

I have cleaned the go cache with `go clean -modcache` with the same result.

I have found both modules https://pkg.go.dev/:

- [github.com/DataDog/datadog-agent/pkg/trace/exportable](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/DataDog/datadog-agent/pkg/trace/exportable@v0.0.0-20201016145401-4646cf596b02)
- [github.com/influxdata/line-protocol/v2](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/influxdata/line-protocol/v2@v2.0.0-20210520103755-6551a972d603)

It seems the exact version exists for *github.com/DataDog/datadog-agent/pkg/trace/exportable* but not for *github.com/influxdata/line-protocol*, but both report the same error anyway.

I have no clue what golang expects here and how to start troubleshooting the issue.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it's a bug (https://github.com/golang/go/issues/45305) due to the introduction of the `retract` directive in `go.mod` in Go 1.16. In fact if you omit the `-m` flag, the command runs fine.

As mentioned in the issue thread, you can add the `-e` flag to move on despite errors:

```
$ go list -mod=readonly -m -u -e -json all

{
    "Path": "github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib",
    "Main": true,
    "Dir": "/Users/me/go/opentelemetry-collector-contrib",
    "GoMod": "/Users/me/go/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/go.mod",
    "GoVersion": "1.16"
}
... much more
```

About the `-e` flag, `go help list`:

> The `-e` flag changes the handling of erroneous packages, those that
> cannot be found or are malformed. [...]
> With the `-e` flag, the list command never prints errors to standard
> error and instead processes the erroneous packages with the usual
> printing. Erroneous packages will have a non-empty ImportPath and
> a non-nil Error field; other information may or may not be missing
> (zeroed).

The bug is fixed in Go 1.17.